# Can I make flash bracketing on my Nikon D7000 automatically take all three shots?

Tags: nikon, nikon-d7000, camera-controls, bracketing

I tried exposure bracketing and it works fine - I set the C(h) and hold the shutter button and it will take all shots while I am holding. However, for flash I have to press 3 times. Is there any setting to have flash bracketing to continuously take the shots?

Comment: Does C(l) make any difference by allowing more recycle time?

Comment: Nop, tried both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need a flashgun to do the job. The built-in flash is not able to fire continuously in Cl or Ch.